# Rename feature-flags to feature-toggles?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [feature-flags](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-flags) tag appears to be about **Feature Flag Toggles**, also called  **Feature Toggles**.

I suggest to call a cat a cat, and rename this tag to [feature-toggles](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-toggles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the tag has to be renamed nor to be set as synonym. There could be valid questions about feature flags (formalism, documentation about them, process of definition), which may not be related to feature **toggles** but to feature **ramp up** which carry a less binary meaning.

Of course this is terminology only, it's just to ease in a classification goal more than objective definition.

So I'd leave those tags as is, and tag edit the questions which need it.

For generic purposes:
If you think questions are wrongly tagged, edit them. If there's too much to edit, then open a meta post to coordinate efforts.

Comment: Interesting answer, didn't realize that ... Have you seen my question I just posted about it?

Comment: Yep, just seen it,  my point was more that feature toggles carry a binary on/off meaning, which is not always the case. So relaxing the terminology on tags is not harmful in my opinion.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens edited to avoid the confusion, I should have said it at first. It probably sounded too obvious in my mind :)

Comment: OK for me. BTW, I "hope" it's OK (in this phase of the private beta), to post these kinds of (possibly basic) questions about some terminology being used (by experts who don't even realizes these kinds of terms / nuances sound like chinese to other people).

Comment: No problem for me. I think this meta shows we can have multiples views about it and the question sounds ok to me. Not eveything has to be named "exactly", we have to cope with reality of our work. :)

Comment: `which may not be related to feature toggles but to feature ramp up`... Could you please add an actual example? I can't really follow - to me it sounds like you'd be talking about `features` in general, not about `feature-flags`.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I'm talking about how those flags impact/enable the feature on a wider point of view of the app. It could be an implementation of `on/off` or `rand(100)<10` to get only 10% of requests getting the feature enabled. (And in extreme cases, the 10 is the result of function taking in account day of week/time, etc. to avoid impacting too much people during high traffic)

Comment: @Tensibai OK. I see. Though one may argue that the toggle would still be enabled, only its behaviour would be different. IMHO rather narrow usage percentage to warrant a non-synonym tag which could also cover the much wider common usage. Either cover that small percentage through the actual question details or create a more specific tag for it, say `feature-flags-gradual` or something like that.

Comment: @DanCornilescu For now, creating a tag with no question will be useless as the cleaning mechanism would remove it... But I just gave my position here, a majority seems to agree with you for a synonym so maybe let's go for that.

Comment: @DanCornilescu the tag creation privilege will be only at 150 in public beta, we will probably have people adding tags by their use more than 'formal' tags and creating them by mistake. Either we will have to request a higher rep to create tags or we'll have to handle the problem when it comes

Comment: Let's handle it when we get there - we may be worrying for nothing. If it proves it's indeed an issue it'd still be a good thing - it means we'd be having a lot of user activity on the site :)

Answer (score 7):

They could also both exist, as synonym tags: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

If we have to choose one of them (as the main and/or only tag) my vote goes with your [feature-toggles](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-toggles) proposal as IMHO it indeed represents the concept better.

Comment: Thank for your support! Your alternative could work for me too. And if some day a Hillary.Trumph tag is needed, then Donald.Clinton would be a possible alternative to that too, no?

Answer (score 2):

More a bit in reply to Tensibal, I don't know about renaming this specific tag, I do know that you do not want both a [feature-flags](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-flags) and a [feature-toggles](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-toggles) tag.

Tags are used to show related questions on the left side. I use tags to set tag favorites and search for questions. You can also let SE sent you a weekly newsletter based on your tags. Also tags are useful for searching for something.

If the tags are too specific, they do not have any use. Try to come up with one tag that covers the whole area.

Comment: May make more sense under [this question](http://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/should-we-allow-or-ban-version-tags). For this specific case, well, I gave my point of view about them, Dan gave another option. You imperiously say we don't want both, but you don't give a real rationale of why one tag for both would be better. (and questions can have multiples tags)

Comment: @Tensibai I'm with 7ochem here: having 2 tags which overlap 80% is not good - those interested would have to follow 2 tags instead of 1. Instead it'd be better to have one common tag plus 2 very specific tags which can be used as filters if needed. Also - without the tag usage definition info in place one can't tell if the 2 tags are/should indeed be synonyms or not, making this discussion rather moot.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Probably a question of culture, I hear feature flag more often as a generic term than feature toggles, and the last is usually with a clear binary implication. Actually we have a grand total of 6 question on those tags, 2 having both. I'm unsure this is a problem ATM.